# Find rows with CheckBox checked DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I put some code in to find what checkboxes have been checked in my DataGridView, but for some reason this isn't working.

I have looping through the rows in the DataGridView:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_assets.Rows

Next
```

Then in here i have casted the first column as a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_assets.Rows

    Dim chk As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DirectCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

Next
```

Then I am checking for all the checkboxes that have been checked:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_assets.Rows

    Dim chk As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DirectCast(row.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

    If chk.Value = chk.TrueValue Then
        MessageBox.Show("Checked")
    End If

Next
```

For some reason even if the checkboxes are checked or unchecked they all hit the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, I guess the casting is the problem.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim chk As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = row.Cells(Column1.Name)
    If chk.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso chk.Value = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Checked: " + chk.RowIndex.ToString())
    End If
Next
```

`Column1` should be the column name of the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` that you are referring.

Comment: You should use `AndAlso` rather than `And` as it's short-circuited, which means that if the left side evaluates to `False`, it won't evaluate the right side. This could help in preventing `NullReferenceExceptions`. Just a little tip. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for the tip, I have changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do in that simple way.

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To dtg.RowCount - 1
        If dtg.Item(0, i).Value = "True" Then
            MsgBox("check")
        End If
    Next
```

I hope to be as helpful

Comment: Where's the explanation? Why should the OP (or anyone else with the same problem) use it? See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a language extension method

Form level variable

```
Private Const CheckBoxColName As String = "Process"
```

Place the following in a code module, not a form or class

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function CheckBoxCount(ByVal GridView As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal Checked As Boolean) As Integer
   Return (From Rows In GridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where CBool(Rows.Cells(ColumnIndex).Value) = Checked).Count
End Function
```

Use the extension method using the private variable above, CheckBoxColName which is the name of the column in the DataGridView as a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

```
If DataGridView1.CheckBoxCount(CheckBoxColName, True) > 0 Then
    Dim Rows = DataGridView1.GetCheckedRows1(CheckBoxColName)
    For Each Row In Rows
        Console.WriteLine(Row.Cells.Item(1).Value)
    Next
End If
```

If you want to use column index rather than column name the following will do so

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function CheckBoxCount(ByVal GridView As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnIndex As Integer, ByVal Checked As Boolean) As Integer
   Return (From Rows In GridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where CBool(Rows.Cells(ColumnIndex).Value) = Checked).Count
End Function
```

Note both allow you to get check or un-checked.

The following gets the actual rows

```
   <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
   <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
   Public Function GetCheckedRows1(ByVal GridView As DataGridView, ByVal ColumnName As String) As List(Of DataGridViewRow)
      Dim Temp = (From Rows In GridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() Where Not Rows.IsNewRow).ToList
      Return (From SubRows In Temp Where CBool(SubRows.Cells(ColumnName).Value) = True).ToList
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you must first verify that TrueValue not null , since according to the documentation , the default is null. And then check if true.

Here Doc : [TrueValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell.truevalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add CheckBox with Name CK1 And Add DataGridView with Name Dgrd and must the first cell be DataGridViewCheckBoxCell And Add the code:

```
  Private Sub CK1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CK1.CheckedChanged
    If CK1.Checked = True Then
        Try
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To Dgrd.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim CHKRow As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = Dgrd.Rows(I).Cells(0)
                If CHKRow.Value = False Then
                    CHKRow.Value = True
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Else
        Try
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To Dgrd.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim CHKRow As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = Dgrd.Rows(I).Cells(0)
                If CHKRow.Value = True Then
                    CHKRow.Value = False
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```